# how to invoke method of annoymous class from the main method of the outer class

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the concept of anonymous class. Could someone please tell me how I can invoke the 'awesomeMethod' from the main method of the LocallClassExample?

```
public class LocalClassExample {

    interface Awesome {

        public void awesomeMethod();
    }

    class AwesomeClass {

        public int finalInt= 10;

        Awesome a1 = new Awesome() {

            @Override
            public void awesomeMethod() {
                System.out.println(finalInt);
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this:

```
new AwesomeClass().a1.awesomeMethod();
```

will invoke the method `awesomeMethod()` on the member variable `a1` (which is something `Awesome`) of the newly created instance of `AwesomeClass`.

It will get more tricky once your main is outside of your `AwesomeClass` - and more so once it's outside of the package. In these cases you'd have to provide a getter like

```
public Awesome getAwesome() { 
  return a1; 
}
```

Which would when invoked still execute the method as defined in your anonymous class.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use this to create inner class object as:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {        
    LocalClassExample.AwesomeClass oi = new LocalClassExample().new AwesomeClass();
  oi.awesomeMethod();
}
```